# Hide iOS navigation bar in Xamarin but retain ability to swipe back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar on iOS from Xamarin but I want to keep the ability to swipe back to the last page.

I've tried doing this:

```
        this.ViewController.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;
```

and this:

```
        this.ViewController.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

in a custom PageRenderer but neither of those hide the navigation bar. If I remove the navigation bar when I'm pushing the page, I also lose the ability to swipe back.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class PageCustomRenderer : PageRenderer, IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (NavigationController != null)
        {
            NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate  = this;
            NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`this` in a PageRender in iOS is already the ViewController so you can  access the `NavigationController` from there.

You will need to make your PageRenderer implement the `IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate` so you can make it the delegate for the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer` of the `NavigationController`

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Do I need to implement any functions from the interface? Because if I just extend the interface and assign `this` to the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate` it doesn't allow me to swipe back. Also the `NavigationBarHidden` property did not hide the navigation bar.

Comment: No it's not necessary as all the members are marked as `IsRequired = false` which means their implementation is optional.

Comment: I've updated my question to show what my renderer currently looks like

Comment: I imagine you are using a `NavigationPage` in your Xamarin project. Also this will make all your pages to hide the NavigationBar, could be a better idea to create a custom `Page` then export the renderer only for those pages.

Comment: I do not want NavigationBar on any of my pages so that's okay. How would I navigate from one page to another without using `NavigationPage`?

Comment: Alright.. You can still "Navigate" between pages without NavigationPage using PushModal. But if you have the NavigationPage and added the above Renderer you should be good by now. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: Adding the above renderer to a NavigationPage does not remove the navigation bar and it also disables the swipe to go back gesture. I tried switching to a regular Page and adding the renderer, which gets rid of the bar and allows me to swipe back.

Comment: The above renderer is not for the `NavigationPage` but for the regular pages which are inside a `NavigationPage`

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I was wrapping the internal pages in a `NavigationPage` too but I realize now that I only need to wrap the main page in a `NavigationPage` so your solution works. Thank you so much!